# Modifying a configuration file

Tags: c++

I want to modify value corresponding to a key in configuration file using cpp. 
Eg:

```
key=value
```

has to be changed to

```
key=new_value
```

I works with 'sed' command, but is there some possible way to do it using cpp way.
Implementation fails when the string to be changed is less than the existing one. Is that not really possible using cpp?

Comment: Of course it's possible. You just write the code to do it. `sed` itself is written in C, and anything that can be written in C can also be written in C++.

Comment: That's possible when I rewrite the contents to another file, but not working in same file

Comment: Why do you believe that after you write another file, that file must now be etched in stone, and cannot be renamed or moved, in order to replace the original file? How do you think `sed` does this?

Comment: Creae a std::map<string, string>, read all file in map splitting the lines at the first '=', modify value like this mymap["key"]="new_value", write all back. It is a 5 liner in C++
Btw.Can you use Qt?

Comment: @ValentinHeinitz , Thank you. This works similar to writing the contents in a buffer, changing it then copying it into the same file right ?

Comment: Could be useful if you want to read and write your config file easily : [link](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap)

Answer (score 1):

You basically only have one option: Rewrite the configuration file, write out all configuration options from the start.

Trying to move around contents of a text file if one line changes length (bigger *or* smaller) is possible, but it's much more work than just rewriting it.

It's either that or the working solution using `sed`, which can be called from inside the program using the `system` function.